# If a sequence converges to some $L \in (a,b)$ then it has a subsequence in $(a,b)$ convergent to $L$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Here's a short lemma I thought of:

---

For every sequence $(s_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{R}$ that converges to some $L\in (a,b)$, there is a subsequence $(s_{n_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $(s_n)$ such that $s_{n_k} \in (a,b)$ for all $k$.

---

It seems fairly obvious to me, and related to the well known fact that if $(x_n)$ is a sequence converging to $L$, then any subsequence of $(x_n)$ also converges to $L$. My idea was that  you just need to find an $N$ big enough so that all the terms of the sequence that follow it are in the band $(a,b)$. I'm wondering if this lemma is true (I can't see how it could be false), and if my proof is valid:

**Proof Attempt:** Since $(s_n)$ converges to $L$, $\exists N_1$ such that $n>N_1 \implies |s_n - L|<b-L$. Similarily, $\exists N_2$ such that $n>N_2 \implies |s_n - L| <L-a \implies a-L<-|s_n - L|$. Define a sequence $(n_k)_{k\in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $n_k=\max\{N_1,N_2\} +k$. Then it follows that since $n_k>\max\{N_1,N_2\}$, we have:
$$
a-L<-|s_{n_k}-L|\leq s_{n_k}-L\leq |s_{n_k}-L| <b-L \\
\implies a-L < s_{n_k}-L <b-L \\
\implies a <s_{n_k}<b
$$
So for all $k$, we have $s_{n_k} \in  (a,b)$ as desired. $\square$

Comment: Proof looks good!

Comment: This is true for metric spaces (using open balls instead of intervals) and likely in more general topological spaces. I am not sure exactly what assumptions are needed for the result to hold, however.